# What does "those" in the sentence refer to?

Tags: grammar, reference

I got this long paragraph from this website.
https://www.esl-lab.com/academic-english/cancer-treatment-script/

I want to know what the word "those" refer to.

Indeed, one might ponder why God allows death and suffering in our world, but for me, such experiences taught me to value family more and kindness for others. You often can’t learn these important attributes in the lap of luxury, and perhaps, such an experience is the greatest and final gift the terminally ill can give ***those*** left behind.

Comment: It means "the ones" or "the persons".

Answer (score 0):

“Those” refers to “people.” In the context of the whole text (not just what you quoted), it refers to those people who dealt with the patient in the months before death, primarily  friends and family.